# Flutter App with Cloud Firestore voting app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

I am developing an app and I want to add a voting functionality. I have followed this tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#8

This does kind of work however, for it to be a voting app I can't have my users vote several times on the same option. I have looked everywhere for a solution but I have not been able to find one. I hope that someone knows a somewhat easy way to do this. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class VotingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VotingPage createState() {
    return _VotingPage();
  }
}

class _VotingPage extends State<VotingPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Top 10 Företagen!')),
      body: _buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('poll').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    return ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
    final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);

    return Padding(
      key: ValueKey(record.name),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(record.name),
          trailing: Text(record.votes.toString()),
    onTap: () => record.reference.updateData({'votes': FieldValue.increment(1)})
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}

class Record {
  final String name;
  final int votes;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['name'] != null),
        assert(map['votes'] != null),
        name = map['name'],
        votes = map['votes'];

  Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$name:$votes>";
}
```

Comment: you can creat List that contain id of users that have been already voted. and before voting check if userId does not exist in that List.

Comment: How would I do that? I am really new to firestore databases so I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Let's say you have a document for (Thing you want user to vote for). you can add a new field to this document "Votes" this field will be a Map that contains userId as key and boolean as value. Something like this: Vote{ "001": true }. this means that user 001 has voted.

Comment: Two approaches: 1) within the item being voted on, store the uid's of the users who have voted and true as a value. Then, when they vote check to see if their UID exists in that list. The structure would be */items/item_being_voted_on/votes/uid_0: true* and then */votes/uid_1: true* etc. 2) Create a rule that only allows a write to the votes node if the uid does not exist. Rules are not filters but it could act as one in this use case by preventing a write.

Comment: I have tried to create a way to sign up and sign in for my app. First i tried to use a tutorial on how to make users able to sign in with email but that didn't work for some unknown reason. I am trying to use google sign in now but I haven't been able to try if it works yet. Do any of you know a good tutorial or explanation on how to get a good sign up/in solution? Thanks everyone for all the helt thus far!